# Alternatives to connect-ensure-login

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I want to use the https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-ensure-login, but the last commit seems to be a year ago. Is there any competing node module to it. I just want to provide only local authentication. Passport http://passportjs.org/ seems to be popular but can passport support local authentication.

Comment: I thunk Connect-ensure-login needs to be used with Passport.

Comment: connect-ensure-login is an extension to Passport, supplying middleware to verify that the user is actually logged in. That the last commit is old does not mean it`s not good.

Answer (score 2):

`connect-ensure-login` is very simple middleware. If there's something else you need that it doesn't offer, just roll your own. For example, I needed the ability to throw a 403 error, instead of redirecting. Here is the current code for `ensureLoggedIn()`:

```
module.exports = function ensureLoggedIn(options) {
    if (typeof options == 'string') {
        options = { redirectTo: options };
    }
    options = options || {};

    var url = options.redirectTo || '/login';
    var setReturnTo = (options.setReturnTo === undefined) ? true : options.setReturnTo;

    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated || !req.isAuthenticated()) {
            if (setReturnTo && req.session) {
                req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl || req.url;
            }
            return res.redirect(url);
        }
        next();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local).  From the docs:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```